# How do I iterate through a dictionary and calculate a rate from two different dictionary elements?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, max, min

I have a dictionary similar to this:

```
table_wood = {'Red': {'Abbreviation': 'R',
                              'Instances': 269601,
                              'Code': '8924',
                              'Discovered': '1876-08-01',
                              'Largest usage': 'Douglas',
                 'Indigo': {'Abbreviation': 'IN',
                              'Instances': 216443,
                              'Code': '2343',
                              'Discovered': '1890-07-03',
                              'Largest usage': 'Freida'}}
```

I need to iterate through the table_wood dictionary and calculate (instances/code) for each dictionary in table_wood. After I do this I need to report which has the greatest number of instances and which has the lowest.

I have tried using for loops to append the pertinent values to empty lists and then using a nested for loop to compare these list values to see which of the original instances is greatest and lowest. 
It involves a great number of empty lists, and I know that there is a better way if I can just store them as new key/value pairs in an empty dictionary.

```
instanceCodeRate = []
colorInstances = []
highestInstance = []
lowestInstance = []
for color in table_wood:
    colorRate.append(color+ ": " +str(round((table_wood[color]["Instances"])/(table_wood[color]["Code"]),2))+ " instances per code.\n")
#print(instanceCodeRate)
    colorInstances.append(table_wood[color]["Instances"])
#print(colorInstances)
    for instance in colorInstances:
        if ((table_wood[color]["Instances"]) == min(colorInstances)):
            lowestInstance.append(color)
        elif ((table_wood[color]["Instances"]) == max(colorInstances)):
            highestInstance.append(color)
#print(instanceCodeRate)
#print(highestInstance)
#print(lowestInstance)
```

When I print(instanceCodeRate) it does it as list elements, which invalidates the "\n" whitespace character I'm trying to print so that each entry has its own line.
My elif works by only storing the largest, but for some reason the if statement which stores the minimum stores multiple list elements where there should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `max` function takes in an optional `key` argument

```py
colors = list(table_wood.keys())
attrs = list(table_wood.values())

max_value = max(attrs, key=lambda: x: x['Instances']/int(x['Code']))
```

this prints out:

```
{'Abbreviation': 'IN',
 'Instances': 216443,
 'Code': '2343',
 'Discovered': '1890-07-03',
 'Largest usage': 'Freida'}
```

This same can be done with `min`